# Injective homomorphism from $\mathrm{Sym}(X)$ to $\mathrm{GL}(V)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

We know that there is an injective homomorphism from symmetric group over $n$ symbols, $\mathrm{S}_n$ to the group of $n \times n$ invertible real matrices, $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$, via the permutation matrix.

I wanted to know if this is also true for symmetric group $\mathrm{Sym}(X)$ over infinite set $X$ to the general linear group $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ over some arbitrary (infinite dimensional) vector space $V$. That is, does there exists an injective homomorphism between these two groups and what might it look like?

Comment: Exactly the same: fix a basis of cardinality $|X|$ and let the symmetric group act by permutting the basis and extending this to a linear automorphism.

Comment: As (essentially) observed, every group $G$ has a faithful representation, namely on the vector space $K^{(G)}$ with basis $G$. On the other hand there is no nontrivial homomorphism from $\mathrm{Sym}(X)$, $X$ infinite, into $\mathrm{GL}_n$ of any field for any field $K$ and finite $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on Arturo’s comment:

Given a set $X$, consider a vector space $V$ with basis $\{e_x\}_{x \in X}$.
For each $\sigma \in \text{Sym}(X)$, define a linear map $P_\sigma \colon V \to V$ by
$$
\forall x \in X, \quad P_\sigma(e_x) = e_{\sigma(x)}.
$$
Thus, $P_\sigma \in \text{GL}(V)$ for every $\sigma \in \text{Sym}(X)$, and the map
$$
P_{(\_)} \colon \text{Sym}(X) \to \text{GL}(V)
$$
is an injective group homomorphism.

Note that if $X$ is finite, then this is the ‘same’ as working with permutation matrices.

Comment: Wonderful! This makes perfect sense.